# "Some required fields" or "Some of required fields"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

Which is correct:

> 1. Some required fields are not highlighted.
> 2. Some of required fields are not highlighted.

If both phrases are correct, is there a difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is correct, but is not the most formal option. In order to correct the second option, it should be changed to 'Some of **the** required fields are not highlighted'.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian. Shall I sound informal if I use the 1st option?

Comment: Yes, you will sound slightly more informal if you use the first option.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it in this way:

Some of **the** required fields are not highlighted.

"**The**" is a definite article and it is used before a noun to define it as something "**specific.**"

If we omit the word "**Some**,"(which is a **Quantifier**) the sentence will still make sense.

**The required fields are not highlighted.**

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. Are both options incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Although both ways you can express that but the second one is more suitable if you add "the"

**some of the required fields**